# How do You pass parameter to myBatis component in Camel?

Tags: parameters, cxf, apache-camel, mybatis, ibatis

How can I provide myBatis component with desired query parameters? I want to perfom a simple Select statement with selection by id. The best solution would be a possibility of having automatic parameter extraction directly from Cxf payload.

I'm not using any domain classes for myBatis mapping.
Route works fine when using getAll method.

So far, my route looks like this:

```
@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {
    from(cxfEndpoint).to("mybatis:getById?statementType=SelectList")
    });
```

and my mapper configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE mapper
    PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Mapper 3.0//EN"
    "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd">

<mapper namespace="User">

  <select id="getAll" resultType="map">
      SELECT * FROM USERS
  </select>

  <select id="getById" parameterType="int" resultType="map">
      SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE ID = #{id}
  </select>

</mapper>
```

Comment: The way I understand the [documentation](https://camel.apache.org/mybatis.html) the body of your exchange has to be an object with a getId() method. The myBatis component will use the returned value to populate the named parameters.

Comment: @Ralf, There isn't any way of doing that without creating dedicated objects?

Comment: At least the documentation does not say anything about being able to use exchange headers or objects stored as an exchange property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just populate your body with the Id itself. It can be just an object of type Integer:

```
from(cxfEndpoint).setBody(Integer.valueOf(123)).to("mybatis:getById?statementType=SelectList")
```

where 123 is your Ide.

Answer (score 2):

You can set a header and pass it to mybatis using inputHeader parameter.

Example:

```
from(cxfEndpoint)
  .setHeader("myHeader").simple("some value")
  .to("mybatis:getById?statementType=SelectList?inputHeader=myHeader")
```

Comment: Thanks, it's not 2014 anymore but can be helpful :)